# Interprocess Communication with HoloLens through tether

Tags: hololens

Is there a way to transfer data between a Microsoft Hololens and a separate program on a desktop through a wired connection, and if so, how? My end goal is to stream live footage onto the HoloLens, but it cannot be wireless.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [Holographic Remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/holographic-remoting-player) over USB.
Setting the remoting IP to 127.0.0.1 in Unity [apparently works](https://forum.unity.com/threads/latency-jitter-issue-with-holographic-remoting.466745/#post-3266543).

Answer (score 1):

I've been investigating this as well. There were some early reports that one could use the IpOverUsbSvc service for this, setting up a port forward. Unfortunately, this is disallowed in recent versions of the operating system, and I have verified with Microsoft support that there is no supported way to transfer data to or from the HoloLens over a tether. See also this discussion: https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/2301/adding-port-forwards-to-hololens